# how to create live search with knockout?

Tags: search, knockout.js, filter

I have project where we need to create a live search with knockout, map with some titles, when the title enter in search field other titles should disappear, I try to use different code but non of them work, and there is no error to help me figure out.

my code for html :
      Filter:

```
    <ul data-bind="foreach: locations">
      <li data-bind="text: title"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And for js:

```
function ViewModel(){
  var self =this;
  this.filter = ko.observable();

  this.locations = ko.observableArray([{ title:'Safa Bridge'},{ title:'Holy Mosque'},{ title:'Diamond Tower'},{ title:'Albaik Resturant'},{ title:'Zamzam'}]);

  this.visibleLocations = ko.computed(function(){
       return this.locations().filter(function(location){
           if(!self.filter() || location.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.filter().toLowerCase()) !== -1)
             return location;
       });
   },this);

}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: bind `visibleLocations` in your `foreach`

Comment: yes, this is working. thank you.